# Conflicting answers when using Complements Principle and the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

The question I'm looking at is:

Andy, Bill, Carl and Dave are 4 students on a team of 10. 5 must be chosen for a tournament, how many teams can be picked if Andy or Bill or Carl or Dave must be on the team.

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle:

Let $A_1 =$ teams with Andy, $A_2 =$ teams with Bill, ect.

$$|A_i| = {9 \choose 4}= 126$$

$$|A_i \cap A_j| = {8 \choose 3} = 56\text{ for }i \neq j$$

$$|A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| = {7 \choose 2} =21\text{ for }i \neq j \neq k$$

$$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = {6 \choose 1} = 6$$

So then $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4| = 4(126) - 6(56) + 3(21) - 6 = 225$

But when I use the complements principle to subtract all teams without Andy, Bill, Carl, and Dave from all teams I get:

$${10 \choose 5} - \displaystyle{6 \choose 5} = 252 - 6 = 246$$

which is not the same. So I'm clearly doing something wrong with one of these but I don't know which one is wrong.

Comment: Why did you add $3(21)$?

Comment: Because the 3 sets $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3, A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4, A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4$ all have 21 different teams and I'm using the inclusion exclusion principle to determine $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4|$

Comment: @MangoPirate : I improved both your TeX formatting and your spelling.  Note that "compliment" with an "i" and "complement" with an "e" are two different words that mean two different things.  The _complement_ (with an "e") of $A$ is something that together with $A$ makes a complete whole.  The resemblance to the spelling of "complete" is not coincidental and enables you to remember which is which.

Comment: @MangoPirate : The coefficients of the other three terms, namely 4, 6, and 1, are all numbers of the form $\binom{4}{j}.$  The number 3 is the only one that doesn't fit this pattern.  Could that be a sign that something's wrong?

Comment: You forgot about $A_1\cap A_3\cap A_4$.

Comment: And now I feel kinda dumb. Such an easy thing to miss but at least I have it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, the $21$ for $|A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k|$ should be multiplied by $4$, not by $3$, since there are $4$ ways to omit one of $4$ students and leave $3$.